# Lavalier microphones for various uses

Tags: lavalier, microphone, car, weapon

Hello,

I'm looking for a lavalier microphone which can make recordings of rifle, car and other vehicles...
I know the DPA 4060 but I found on the Internet countryman C3, Rode lavalier, AKG, Audio-technica, for less dear.

In this price range, which would you recommend me ?
By thanking you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I´d go DPA, yes they are expensive, but they are very good and useful for pretty much
any field.

If not ,

Voice Technologies (VT 500 or different one)

TRAM Tr 50 (versatile, hiding under cloth not toooo good)

a Sanken Cos 11 is fine (also good for hiding under cloth)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to the Countryman B3, I don't think they make a C3.  I would NOT recommend this mic for recording the sources you mentioned above.

I have a whole stock of B3s that I use for live theatre reinforcement.  They are a little heavy on the high-mids, which is a feature for my use, but I think for recording something more true, you'd want something with a flatter response.

Also, while you can get them in several sensitivities, I don't think they could handle the high SPL, transient nature of recording gunfire.

Comment: It's the Countryman B3 effectively, sorry...Thank you for your answer. 

I also saw the sennheiser Me-2, can it suit for my use or it is to be disadvised ?

it is less expensive than the others which would have allowed me to take several.

Comment: My apologies, but I am not personally familiar with the ME2.  I have had a challenge finding specific specs on it regarding response and sensitivity.  I would venture a guess that the biggest hurdle with these mics would be their sensitivity, if you are trying to record gunshots.  

Just out of curiosity, why are you looking at lavalieres for this application?  I don't do much field recording:  I am primarily a live guy, but when I do go sfx gathering I am usually carrying a shotgun and a pair of cardioid condensers or a m/s rig.  What advantage are you getting from the lav?

Comment:  I have already a shotgun mic and a pair of cardioid condensers, but I saw several videos of sound engineer using lavaliers microphones in complement for the recording of rifle and car engine, so I will want to test and a lavalier can always be useful in your equipment.

Answer (score 0):

BMC professional sound lavalier mic's would sound great for recording machine noise and harsh noises

Answer (score 0):

I've done a bunch of motorcycles and cars with cos-11s they work well and can be placed on the driver nicely